# Entity framework core lazy loading not performed when inserting new instances

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading

I have two classes:

- `Campaign` which references a class customer:

  ```
  public class Campaign
  {
      [Key]
      [Required]
      public int id { get; set; }
      public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
      [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
      public virtual Customer customer { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- And `Customer`:

  ```
  public class Customer
  {
      [Key]
      [Required]
      public int id { get; set; }
      [Required]
      public string name { get; set; }
      [Required]
      public double turnover { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<Campaign> campaigns { get; set; }
  }
  ```

Here's is an insert method:

```
async Task<Campaign> ICampaignRepository.InsertCampaign(Campaign campaign)
{
    try
    {
        _context.Campaigns.Add(campaign);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return campaign;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

I'm using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies` package for *lazy loading*.

After adding a campaign instance having a `customerId`, the `customer` is not lazy loaded in the inserted object. Please note that I tried to fetch the campaign by `id` before returning it, but the problem persists, and I want to avoid loading the `customer` explicitly.

Lazy loading is perfectly working when performing fetch operations on existing records.

Comment: EF Core isn’t lazy loading anything by default (that’s a good thing btw.), and I don’t think automatically loading related things on added entities is supported at all.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies package for lazy loading

Comment: The entity you get passed to your function very likely isn’t a proxy entity though. So the lazy loading magic won’t happen there. You might need to create the object with `_context.CreateProxy()`.

Comment: `_context.CreateProxy()` should be called to create the parent object or the navigation property ?

Comment: The `Campaign` object that you are adding to the context.

Comment: Can you clarify how to use `CreateProxy()` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to [poke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216074/poke)

The solution is to:

1. Create a proxy for your entity using [`CreateProxy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.proxiesextensions.createproxy?view=efcore-2.1):

   ```
   Campaign toCreate = _context.Campaigns.CreateProxy();
   ```
2. Transfer new values to your proxy object:

   ```
   _context.Entry(toCreate).CurrentValues.SetValues(Campaign);
   ```
3. Finally, save your proxy object to the context:

   ```
   _context.Add(toCreate);
   await _context.SaveChangesAsync();`
   ```

Here's the full method:

```
async Task<Campaign> ICampaignRepository.InsertCampaign(Campaign campaign)
{
    Campaign toCreate = _context.Campaigns.CreateProxy();
    _context.Entry(toCreate).CurrentValues.SetValues(campaign);
    _context.Add(toCreate);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return toCreate;
}
```