# UseLazyLoadingProxies codefirst null navigation property only after database creation

Tags: sqlite, lazy-loading, code-first, ef-core-6.0

## Problematic code (Present in Core.run() below)

```
user.UserWordRequests.Add(
    new UserWordRequest
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now,
        Word = word
    }
);
```

## Decription of problem

1. Database doesn't exists
2. Exec first time console program, code above in `user.UserWordRequests` is null. **Expected value is empty list**.
3. Database now exists because step 2 has created it.
4. Exec console program again, now `user.UserWordRequests` is empty list (or filled with data, depends of data in db).

More data, here is user object in step 2:

[image]

And here in step 4:

[image]

## Usefull code

### Database models

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserWordRequest> UserWordRequests { get; set; }
}

public class Word
{
    public Word()
    {
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserWordRequest> UserWordRequests { get; set; }
}

public class UserWordRequest
{
    public UserWordRequest()
    {
    }
    
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int WordId { get; set; }
    public virtual Word Word { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }  
}
```

### Main program

```
class Program
{
    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = 
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging(loggingBuilder =>
            {
                loggingBuilder.ClearProviders(); // Disable console messages
            })
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                // Auto mapping config !!!
                var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                .SetBasePath(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory))
                                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                                .Build();
                var settings = config/*.GetSection("GeneralSection")*/.Get<Config>();

                // AddHostedService
                services
                .AddHostedService<ConsoleHostedService>()
                .AddDbContext<DataBaseContext>
                (
                    options =>
                    options
                        .UseLazyLoadingProxies(true)
                        .UseSqlite(
                           settings.General.DataBaseConnection                               
                        )
                        ,
                    ServiceLifetime.Singleton,
                    ServiceLifetime.Singleton
                    
                )
                //.AddEntityFrameworkProxies()                    
                .AddSingleton((Config) => { return settings; })
                .AddSingleton<Logger>()
                .AddSingleton<Util.File>()
                .AddSingleton<Core>()
                .AddSingleton<DataBaseContext>()                  
                ;
            }).Build();
        host.Services.GetService<DataBaseContext>().Database.Migrate();

        // Then run application
        host.Run();
    }
}
```

### Console hosted service class

```
public class ConsoleHostedService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _appLifetime;
    private readonly Core _Core;
    private readonly Logger _Logger;
    private readonly DataBaseContext _db;

    public ConsoleHostedService(
        IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime,
        Core Core,
        Logger Logger,
        DataBaseContext DataBaseContext)
    {
        _appLifetime = appLifetime;
        _Core = Core;
        _Logger = Logger;
        _db = DataBaseContext;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _appLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() =>
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    // Start program
                    //_db.Database.Migrate();
                    _Core.run();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    _Logger.Log(Logger.LogType.Error, "", e);
                }
                finally
                {
                    // Stop the application once the work is done
                    _appLifetime.StopApplication();
                }
            });
        });

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

### DatabaseContext

```
public class DataBaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataBaseContext(DbContextOptions<DataBaseContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public virtual DbSet<Word> Words { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Log> Logs { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<UserWordRequest> UserWordRequests { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     ❗❗❗ We need this class only for doing add-migration, but this is not used by anyone
    /// </summary>
    public class DataBaseContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<DataBaseContext>
    {
        public DataBaseContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataBaseContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=this_name_is_not_used.db");

            return new DataBaseContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
```

### Core class ❗❗❗  PROBLEMATIC CODE

```
public Core(DataBaseContext DataBaseContext, Logger Logger, File File, Config Config)
{
    _db = DataBaseContext;
    _Logger = Logger;
    _File = File;
    _Config = Config;

    _Random = new Random();

    _Logger.Log(Logger.LogType.Info, "Core");
}

public void run()
{
    try
    {
        ... some code
        
        var word = _db.Words.FirsOrDefault();
        var user = _db.Users.FirsOrDefault();
        
        // ‼‼‼ PROBLEMATIC CODE 
        user.UserWordRequests.Add(
            new UserWordRequest
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now,
                Word = word
            }
        );
        
        _db.SaveChanges();
        ... some code
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        _Logger.Log(Logger.LogType.Error, "", e);
    }
    
}
```

## Versions used

net6.0 and:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="6.0.0" />
```

Comment: It all depends where `user` comes from in the first code fragment. Your descriptions "code is executed" and "when I exec code" are too vague, You should show the code that actually runs.

Comment: @GertArnold see edit post, when I say code executed and exec code I refer to exec main program in vs... no more . User comes from same code because is a main execution 2 times, one without database created and one with database created.

Comment: Doesn't tell me where `user.UserWordRequests.Add(...` runs.

Comment: @GertArnold done, I think now is more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Summary, leason learned

Use [create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31405958/entity-framework-6-create-vs-new) or [createProxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57179749/entity-framework-core-lazy-loading-not-performed-when-inserting-new-instances) instead `new` for avoid errors.

### Error explained

First time console app is executed, when database is created, code created users with `new` instead `Create` or `CreateProxy`:

```
var user = new User();
user.prop = "value";
...
db.Users.Add(user)
```

Later, inside first time console app execution, application executes this code and `UserWordRequests` is null instead empty list.

```
var user = db.Users.Where(...).FirstOrDefault();

user.UserWordRequests.Add(
    new UserWordRequest
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now,
        Word = ...
    }
);
```

The solution comes using `Create` or `CreateProxy` for user creations.

```
var proxy = _db.Users.CreateProxy();
proxy.Name = user.Name;
_db.Users.Add(proxy);
```

Then, `UserWordRequests` is empty list, not null.

But... why second time this does not happen? Because users are created in database and the code did not execute the inserts, it obtained them with a database query.